# How to show full content in wordpress archives?

Tags: wordpress, archive

I want to show full content in wordpress archives/tags/category instead of excerpt. How do I do this? Is this a theme specific issue where I have to change the code, or is there a universal way to make my website show full content if i wanted to?

Answer (score 0):

That is a specific theme modification you need to perform, and that's not possible in WP Admin area.

To be specific modify the `archive.php` and replace the occurrence of `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()`